# jsf displaying alert outside managed bean

Tags: jsf

In the existing application there is a requirement to put some filter when any service is being called from the managed bean.

Filter is across the service call and will do some configured validation either using some config file or Rules Engine and based on it will popup a message that need user input and accordingly will proceed.

Problem is that ones the request goes out from managed bean i am not getting the way to popup a message with user input.

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit difficult without code to see but you can try calling FacesContext and create FacesMessage object into a java filter.

Comment: If the request does not pass trough the faces servlet first there will be no faces context.

Comment: Login.xhtml ----on click of a button----->login () in LoginController.java (Managed Bean) ----call to the service-----> login() in LoginService.java

Comment: There is a around filter configure for login() method of LoginService.java. In this filter based on the validation rules need to pop up an alert or user input dialog